# Changes made in WinPE to x:\ don't stick

Tags: winpe

I need to automatically update the software I've included with my WinPE image, but whatever changes I make to the flash drive don't stick after reboot. It updates successfully, but the files that I've copied get deleted and the old ones somehow come back after I reboot, forcing the updater to run again.

What do I have to do to get changes made to x:\ to stick, or is it even possible?
I don't see where this has been asked anywhere else so forgive me if someone has already gotten the answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is; instead of making changes to x:\, the software will find the drive's volume number by its name through a batch script, then compare a version.txt on the flash drive with a version.txt on the server. If the version on the server is newer, it downloads an updated boot.wim to the WinPE sources folder and restarts.